# Can't restart apache (98)Address already in use, even after I kill process

Tags: process, apache, kill

I'm unable to (re)start apache because port 80 is already in use:

```
[root@out-dev log]# service httpd start
Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using <ip> for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

So I tried identifying the process which was using port 80:

```
[root@out-dev log]# netstat -npl | grep ':80'
tcp 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN 3840/httpd
```

It's httpd! That's odd to me because the service httpd is apparently not running:

```
[root@out-dev log]# service httpd status
httpd is stopped
```

Anyway, I tried killing the process, but as soon as I do, a new process appears, taking control of port 80. And all the while, `service httpd status` indicates that httpd is not running.

```
[root@out-dev log]# kill -9 3840
[root@out-dev log]# netstat -npl | grep ':80'
tcp 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN 3842/httpd
```

Comment: You might have more success asking this question on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: service can/will lie to you. in many cases it'll only check for the exists of a pid file and read out its contents, rather than doing `ps -ax|grep ...` and extracting pids from "real" data. check that there's no httpd.pid file lying around.

Comment: @Marc, running your command, I see several processes located at /usr/sbin/httpd. I didn't set up this machine, for instance: `daemon    7655  0.0  0.4  63556  4740 ?        S    17:14   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd`. Do you have any idea what I should do? Kill them all?

Comment: @Cyle, I see that you're right. I don't suppose there's a way to migrate this thread to that site?

Comment: @jellicle: yes. the pid recorded in the pid file will be the original "master" apache process, the one that starts up as root, binds to port 80, then drops down to another account before it starts forking off the handler children. normally killing that root process will kill the children too, but stuff will hit the fan and not work right. kill ALL apache processes.